# How do I retrieve the Windows Hard Drive InstallDate?

Tags: delphi, wmi

In the Windows device manager I can find the HardDrive InstallDate.
How Can I extract this Installation date with code? (using Delphi)

Allthough the WMI has in the Win32_DiskDrive class a InstallDate property but when running the WMI code the result for InstallDate is NULL.

[image]

this NULL is the result of the MagWmiGetPropStr function:

```
function MagWmiGetPropStr (wmiProp: ISWbemProperty): string ;
var
  I: integer ;
begin
  result := '';
  if VarIsNull(wmiProp.Get_Value) 
  then result := 'NULL'
  else begin
     case wmiProp.CIMType of
        wbemCimtypeDatetime:
            result := wmiProp.Get_Value;
  end;
end ;
```

the "wmiProp.Get_Value" seems to be Null so this WMI cannot find an InstallDate.
Where does Windows Device Manager get the Hard Drive Install date or What can I do to make WMI get the Hard drive InstallDate ?
Thank you.

Comment: When you look in the device manager, the drive's install date is non-null, right?

Comment: @RobKennedy yes indeed the InstallDate in the device Manager is the actual Installation date and is non-null. 
I would like to know how I can retrieve this InstallDate, seems it is not in WMI